# Re-route/proxy FTP connections to different VM's depending on username

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, ftp, virtualization

I have a setup of several virtual LAMP servers. Incoming http requests are routed with virtual domains and mod_proxy in apache2. Now I need to set it up so my different users can access there respective servers via FTP.

I have no idea how this is to be done, and Google will not give me a straight answer.

All the best,
Björn T Gustafsson

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP protocol specifies the `Host:` header which the client provides to tell the server what virtual host it expects to see.

The FTP protocol has no headers.  IIS has something they call FTP virtual hosts, but instead of a header, it automatically creates users with usernames like `www.example.org|username` and `www.example.com|username` so that the user enters the hostname they want to log in to as part of their username, but that's on a single server.

I don't think there are any reverse ftp proxies that will sit on a connection long enough for the client to send the USER command, but if there are they might be able to choose a server to redirect to based on the username.